# Compile error Font T2A/cmr/m/n/12=larm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

Tags: texstudio, mactex, mac

I have recently installed MacTeX and TeXstudio on my macbook air 2013 (os x el captain 10.11.2) and tried to compile a file but got the error[image][image]
How to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you install the full MacTeX?

Comment: @egreg I used this link: http://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

Comment: Can you open a Terminal window, issue the command `mktextfm larm1200` and tell what happens?

Comment: @egreg i've done it, and now have another error 
Font T2A/cmr/m/n/20.74=larm2074 at 20.74pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \maketitle
pdfTeX error (font): invalid font identifier. \maketitle

Comment: @egreg thank you!!! now it works fine:) second time I had some errors in my code